# Notifying UI on the "on data" event of Node api method

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, routes

I need to know if there is a way to notify the UI front end JS file from the "on data" event of the node api method.
This is the code that I have currently on the front end JS

```
var filter = {
    user: username,
    time: time
}

$.get('/getZipFolder/'+JSON.stringify(filter),function(data){
    console.log(data.filename);
});
```

On the Node.js side, this is the code:

```
exports.getZipFolder= function(req, res, next) {
    var request = JSON.parse(req.params.obj);
    var call = myChatClient.getZipFolderName(request);
    call.on('data', function(bitem) {
        var zipFileName = 'myFolder.zip'
        res.json({"filename":zipFileName});
    });
};
```

The response:

> res.json({"filename":zipFileName});

Never reaches the UI front end JS and this statement Never gets called:

> console.log(data.filename);

Is there a way to notify the UI in such a manner on the `on data` event of the node api method?

**Note:** The Node JS process does not end when the `res.json({"filename":zipFileName});` is sent to the UI on the `on data` event, but it goes on in the backend to do other processing stuff, and the UI cannot wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may happen during the handle of `myChatClient.getZipFolderName` . Maybe it cannot trigger the callback which means the server never response the UI. Add `return` to `res` or not doesn't matter under this condition.

Comment: it does call the callback function on the `on data` and creates the ZIP folder. However, when i try to send the zip folder filename back to UI `res.json({"filename":zipFileName});`, it does not do so.
and yes this service: `myChatClient.getZipFolderName` is ongoing and doesn't stop when the zip folder filename is sent to UI in the `on data` event of the node method